# Cannot ping domain without subdomain with Caddy

Tags: web, server, proxy, dns, caddy

I have a domain example.com that i am trying to set up with caddy as a reverse proxy as well as static file host.

I have set up an a record pointing to the host ip with a wildcard record *

In my caddyfile i have this:

```
example.com {
  root * somefiles
  file_server
}

subdomain.example.com {
 reverse_proxy 127.0.0.1:someport
}
```

I disabled ufw for this test

When i access example.com, i get an NXDOMAIN error. Pinging example.com gives me a host not found exception. However, accessing subdomain.example.com works fine and pinging it reveals the underlying ip

Anyone know the cause of this?

Comment: You can try https://caddy.community - also you need to list your real domains, this could easily be a dns issue.

Comment: "When i access example.com, i get an NXDOMAIN error. " You forgot to put an `A` record at apex of your domain.